# Firemonkey: How open the combobox dialog?

Tags: combobox, firemonkey, setfocus

I used `cbx1.setFocus` but this code not open the dialog with the options. I need a command that open the dialog without touch the combobox. This is because I'm using the `Key = vkReturn` button, so, when the user finish type his name, he press the 'Next' button from the virtualKeyboard and change the focus to the next item, which is a combobox.

Comment: `cbx1.DropDown`